# Minecraft won't open, crashes as soon as I launch it with an Ubuntu VM

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, virtualization

I am trying to load minecraft 1.8.8 on an Ubuntu virtual machine, however everytime I load it it immediately crashes, doesn't give me a crash report or anything, it just says 'Exit code: 0'. I am giving it 2 GB of ram, and people are saying that should be enough so I am really not sure what's wrong.

My JVM arguments:
`-Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M`

My Ubuntu version:
20.04.1

Comment: Same issue here, I am running windows 10 with modded minecraft 1.15.2 BUT i did notice the minecraft luancher was uptaded today this is most likley the issue. Tell me if you find a fix.

Comment: Why are you doing this in a VM? Without GPU passthrough if graphics do somehow work, they don't work well.

Comment: What is the host OS and why aren't you just running Minecraft there?

Comment: make sure you're using the right java version (java 8 i think) and give it at least 4GB RAM

Answer (score -1):

Trying allocating more RAM, at least 4GB and make sure accelerated graphics is on for the VM.